# Path of log file

Tags: java, eclipse, java.util.logging

I have created a logger using:

```
private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(newClass.class.getName());
```

but where can see the generated log file in my system/workspace ?

Comment: Have you specified the handlers for logger??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Default, it will not write those messages into a log file.

You will have to specify a file Handler to which the log messages to write.

```
Handler handler = new FileHandler("logfile.log", size, rt_cnt);
Logger.getLogger("").addHandler(handler);
```

Based on the file name and location which you are providing in the FileHandler constructor, it will create the file and write the message

Comment: should I write this handler in the same java file(where I created the logger) or in a separate property file?

Comment: you can write it in the same class. If you want to make it generic and to use across multiple java files then its better to write in a properties files and load the same through LogManager.